# How to detect seven-segment digits from a picture on a computer screen with Python?

Tags: python, ocr, seven-segment-display

I need to detect seven-segment digits from a pc screen and then print the digits it sees out or gives the information to other programs so I can use the information. I would also like it to do it automatically without user input. I really haven't found answers to my problem because usually, the people are trying to detect the digits from a real-life picture, not from a pc screen.

Here is the picture I would like the digits to be detected from:

[image: seven-segment timer]

Things that I have tried:

I have tried tesseract, but it just reports that there isn't anything there.

I have also seen this: https://github.com/auerswal/ssocr
but I don't quite understand how to use it.

Note: The color of the digits can range from green to yellow to red depending on the time left (Idk if that's important)

Second Note: The background isn't always black. It can range from any color really, but not as brightly as the seven-segment timer.

Comment: I would look into this library https://github.com/suyashkumar/seven-segment-ocr

Comment: @quest Hello! I have also seen this: https://github.com/auerswal/ssocr
but I don't quite understand how to use it. It also seems like that is meant for videos and not photos.

Comment: ah ok. Does your picture only have these digits and colon?

Comment: you didn't get my questions. Let me rephrase. Are there other objects in the picture as well or only the digits? I was thinking in the direction of using a ANN and for that you will have to know if localization has to be performed before classification.